# How to avoid "no module installed" in Python 3

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip, python-idle

Every single dependency I try to install results in a ton of troubleshooting before I can get IDLE to recognise that it's installed.

I'm on a Mac, and I'm using the Terminal's pip install. I also have two versions of IDLE – one for Python 2, the other for 3.

`pip install` says "`beautifulsoup`" is installed

`pip3 install` says "`beautifulsoup`" is installed, and yet it doesn't appear that IDLE knows that it is.

I've tried "`import beautifulsoup4, import beautifulsoup, from bs4 import beautifulsoup`..."

Why is this happening for every dependency I install?

Comment: `from bs4 import Beautifulsoup`, It's uppercase.

Comment: Have you tried it in the python interpreter? in command line? Is it a problem only with idle?

Comment: I'm giving up on IDLE. It sucks.

Comment: No idle is good. @MD.KhairulBasar it's not `Beautifulsoup` it's `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: @s_vishnu oh yep ! you are right.

Comment: @yeeeeee You are right, IDLE has no idea what modules are installed.  It is just a front end to the python binary that runs it.  It passes your code to compile() and the result of that to exec().  Import errors come from python and as long as there is no sys.path difference, there should be no difference in the result of `import x` fed to a python binary directly or via IDLE (or any other IDE that does not change your code).  If there is in a particular case, it would be a bug somewhere that should be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `beautifulsoup` or `Beautifulsoup`

Try this `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Comment: I got it eventually.